# Monit use alert along with exec

Tags: monit

I have rule like this:

```
if memory usage > 85% for 10 cycles then alert
```

I want to notify not only via email but also via slack. So I can add second line like this:

```
if memory usage > 85% for 10 cycles then exec /path/to/slack.rb
```

It's annoying when you have multiple rules and you have to duplicate each line.
Is it possible to use alert and exec together? Something like this:

```
if memory usage > 85% for 10 cycles then alert and exec /path/to/slack.rb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there is no need to have two rules. The second one (with `exec`) is enough. If you have `set alert` configured monit will alert you when a limit is matched. But if you don't want to receive an alert, use an additional rule `noalert your@email`.

Comment: What about a similar case, with many check "if ... alert ..." : is it possible to keep the alerts and write only one final "if alert then exec ..." ?